# Metabox Geolocation Extension: How to dynamically update Restriction based on users country selection

Tags: wordpress, geolocation, meta-boxes

[Meta Box Extension: Geolocation](https://metabox.io/plugins/meta-box-geolocation/)

I need to make the country restriction dynamically updated through user selection of a select dropdown containing the country iso2 values. I've tried to find any documentation that is similar to what I'm aiming for, but by far no luck.

There is no support forum as well for the plugin + extension that seems to have the answer or example that I'm looking for.

Basically what I wanna do is:
User selects a country (ie: United States) -> The expected result is the address field will limit the addresses to those in US only.